# Efficiantly change matrix's elements at special positions

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix like:

```
0001111111110
0010000000001
0100000000010
0100000000010
0010000000001
0011111111110
```

I want it to fill inner zeros with ones:

```
0001111111110
0011111111111
0111111111110
0111111111110
0011111111111
0011111111110
```

There are a lot of matrixes and they are large.

I have only 1 idea for this moment:

```
for i, row in enumerate(mask):
    if sum(row) > 0:
        top_one = np.argmax(row)
        bot_one = len(row) - np.argmax(row[::-1]) - 1
    mask[i, top_one:bot_one] = 1
```

**There can be only ONE inner zeros zone!**(easy case)

I want the most efficiant and beautiful solution, please

**EDIT:** Why doesnt the `scipy` methos work?

```
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])

scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes(a).astype(int)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: Define inner zeroes. What if there are two separate regions of zeroes enclosed by ones? Do you just want to flood fill from a certain point?

Comment: @AlexHall Yes, that's very unpleasured case, i'm thining about it right now. Of course, i want diffrent regions to be filled correctly. Can you give me ideas?

Comment: It's up to you, I don't know what your final goal is.

Comment: @AlexHall OKay, i'am edditing it right now

Comment: @AlexHall done. I just want a very time efficiant way!

Comment: What if the 1s don't make a closed loop?

Comment: @AlexHall You are considering cases i'm thinking of right now!! i really have no good idea,what to do, if loops are not closed and there ARE several zones. I will be very happy, if you give me one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a function in scipy.ndimage to do that:

```
scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes(mask).astype(int)
```

results in

```
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: How it deals with several masks? and what if loops of masks are not closed??

Comment: you can simply loop over all "mask" arrays you have. You have to define what output you desire if loops are not closed

Comment: I mean the case, where i have SEVERAL loops in ONE matrix

Comment: all loops will be filled

Comment: obviously there are no connected loops anymore. It does not correspond to the original question. Btw. I think it's not correct to modify and re-open the question after an accepted answer was given.